# Edit Text in custom dialog always return null values

Tags: android, android-edittext

Sir , I am going to create the custom dialog  with some editText fields and which the values of the selected item of the Listview is drawn and set into the value of the EditText.

But when it comes to the execution , it always turn null as follows

```
    08-29 18:08:06.211: D/dalvikvm(10652): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 219K, 6% free 21317K/22663K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
08-29 18:08:07.811: D/debug getCovreage Address(10652): 15
08-29 18:08:07.831: D/txtB(10652): null
08-29 18:08:07.831: D/txtFt(10652): null
08-29 18:08:07.831: D/txtFr(10652): null
```

Would you please tell me how to initialise the editText in the custom editText , set the values and get the values of the EditText ?

```
coverageList.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);                                                                                           
        coverageList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                curservid = resultList.get(arg2).get("Block").toString();
                Log.d("debug getCovreage Address" , curservid);

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(EOrderCheckCoverage.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_coverage_open_order);
                dialog.setTitle("Open Order");

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                final EditText txtB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBlock);
                Log.d("txtB" , String.valueOf(txtB));
                final EditText txtFt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFlat);
                Log.d("txtFt" , String.valueOf(txtFt));
                final EditText txtFr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBlockFloor);
                Log.d("txtFr" , String.valueOf(txtFr));

                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String a = txtB.getText().toString();
                        String b = txtFt.getText().toString();
                        String c = txtFr.getText().toString();                                                          
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(EOrderCheckCoverage.this, a + " " + b  + " " + c, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });     

                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: try using this lib https://github.com/SiddheshShetye/fragmentDialogLib for fragment dialogs if it fits your requrement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your EditText are available in the dialog layout then you must have to use reference of the dialog layout as parent first.

So please if your EditText are available in the dialog then use something like below code:

```
 // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            final EditText txtB = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtBlock);
            Log.d("txtB" , String.valueOf(txtB));
            final EditText txtFt = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtFlat);
            Log.d("txtFt" , String.valueOf(txtFt));
            final EditText txtFr = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtBlockFloor);
            Log.d("txtFr" , String.valueOf(txtFr));
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way,

```
final EditText txtB = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtBlock);
```

Since you are not referring the view where the EditText is bound, Android looks for it in a wrong place and you keep getting NPE. Adding the dialog object to the above statement will make it initialize properly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do everything eclipse is telling you^^. Define the objects global and initialize them in the methode's body.

And for future times define a methode in your activites like this:

```
public <T> T castViewById(int id){
    return (T) findViewById(id);
}
```

after that you can write:

```
EditText te = castViewById(R.id.myview);
```